# Django fixtures: Cannot assign data to textfield using json file

Tags: python, mysql, django, json

I am trying to load data into mysql database using Django's "manage.py loaddata" command. When I try to load the file containing following json content, I get an error

```
DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture 
'my_json.json': [u'No JSON object could be decoded']
```

When I remove the field named "extra_data", then the data is loaded succesfully. I have discovered that the field "extra_data" is a textfield due to which it is causing the error. How can I specify textfield correctly in json for insertion?

```
[
{
    "pk": 2,
    "model": "auth.user",
    "fields": {
        "username": "JamesButt"
    }
}, {
    "pk": 1,
    "model": "socialaccount.socialaccount",
    "fields": {
        "uid": "JamesButt",
        "last_login": "2013-11-22 11:11:11",
        "user": 2,
        "provider": "1",
        "extra_data": "something",
        "date_joined": "2013-11-22 11:11:11"
    }
}
]
```

Comment: afaik textfields are serialized as simple strings in json. Can you post the model? Have you removed or added `extra_data` recently and maybe forgot to execute `syncdb`?

Comment: I am using django-alluth and the models are obtained there. You can check out [models.py](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/models.py)

Actually its not a textfield but is defined as extra_data = JSONField(default='{}')

Comment: @YerayDiazDiaz The string inside should also be a valid json. Thanks it is now solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extra_data = JSONField(default='{}')`, try using a JSON document:

```
"extra_data": { "data": "something" }
```